# pdo execute gives 500 internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, iis-7

```
$dbh= new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=prawntube', "uname", "aaaaa");
$s=$dbh->prepare("call smessage_select(:sm,:lang)");
$s->bindParam(":sm", $sm,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$s->bindParam(":lang", $lang,PDO::PARAM_STR);
/*
    $dbh->execute();
    $title=$s->fetch();
*/
```

when I comment out the segment, I have no errors. Otherwise, I get internal server error 500. I am using mysql driver and my connection string is fine. Any guesses?

Comment: If that was a production password, please change it, I guarantee you that I'm not the only one who caught it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) does not have an `execute` method. You probably meant to write `$s->execute`, or (less likely) `$dbh->exec` or `$dbh->query`.

Comment: OP is obviously using prepared statmenets (`$dbh->bindParam`). So no `$dbh->query` :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Sure. Just laying all the options on the table.

Comment: @Jon TBH it's more confusing that way, since as Madara said, the others options are kinda wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$s->execute()`, not `$dbh->execute()`.  Look over the PDO documentation .. there are a lot of methods on the statement object (`$s`) and the connection object (`$dbh`) that you will probably need to use, so you should familiarize yourself with the API.